# Name of an element of an element of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there some way of notating that an object can be related to a set through element relations, even if it is not an element of the set? e.g. $a\not\in\{\{a,b\},\{c,d\}\}$, but $a\in\{a,b\}\in\{\{a,b\},\{c,d\}\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is. It's called a transitive closure of a set and is (roughly) defined by

$$\mathrm{tcl}(A) = A \cup \bigcup A \cup \bigcup \bigcup A \cup \ldots$$

In your example $a \in \mathrm{tcl}( \{ \{ a, b \}, \{ c, d \} \} )$.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do this is to write $$a\in\cup S$$ which reads as "$a$ is among the elements of the sets in $S$". In your example, $$\cup\{\{a,b\}, \{c,d\}\} = \{a, b, c,d\}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wasn't clear enough in my question, but I wanted something that would act to any depth, which is why I went with Adayah's answer.